# How would you implement a save and create another feature on a model in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to implement a save and create another instance of a model but I can't understand how routing works.

```
def save_and_create
  @book_condition = BookCondition.new(params[:book])
  if @book_condition.save
    flash[:notice] = t('app.messages.success')
    redirect_to new_book_condition_url
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Above is what I wrote. How would you do it? How would you route it?

Thanks